# As a non EU Citizen and dependent to German Blue card holder, work for Czech Company while residing in Germany

Tags: work-permit, non-citizens

MY partner is an EU Bluecard holder and living in Germany (works for a German company). As a dependent to him (with German residence permit), can I work for a Czech Company as a remote employee while living with my partner?

I registered in Germany and I also have work authorization in Czech Republic.

Please suggest.

Comment: Do you also have a German work permit ("Erwerbstätigkeit gestattet" on your Aufenthaltstitel I think)? If yes, I see no obvious problem here. You can ask at your Ausländerbehörde if really unsure. And you should find out where you have to pay taxes and social insurance, i.e. in CZ or in D or in both.